# AWS Lambda Error: Process exited before completing request

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have tried all the solutions found on other similar stack overflow questions but I still get this error. I'm a beginner and have only just started learning this. So, I'm not sure if I'm following the solutions right. But here's my code. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
host     : 'host',
user     : 'user',
password : 'password',
database : 'student',
connectionLimit : 10,               
  multipleStatements : true
});


exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {


  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

  connection.query("SELECT name FROM 'student'.'course'", function (err, results, fields) {

      if (err) {
        console.log("NOT-CONNECTED!");
        connection.destroy();
        throw err;
    } else {
        // connected!
        console.log("CONNECTED!");
        console.log(results);
        callback(err, results);
        connection.end(function (err) { callback(err, results);});
    }
    });
 });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout or memory from default settings under Basic settings?  Also, are any of your console.log messages actually executing?

Comment: The message "Process exited before completing request" means that the Javascript function exited before calling `context.done` (or `context.succeed`, `callback` etc.).
You can try increase function's timeout (default is 6s), I think the `getConnection` function takes more time, you can add `console.log` step by step to detect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your error scenario, you are never calling `callback`.  You'll need to do something like -

```
if (err) {
        console.log("NOT-CONNECTED!");
        connection.destroy();
        callback(null, err)// or callback(err)
    }
```